# stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: is removing too many characters

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, uilabel

I have a string that represents the title from an article obtained from rss feeds. The string has white spaces at the end so I need to trim the string.

```
cell.title.text = [untrimmedTitle stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

However, the new string doesn't display the entire title. For example, "Abortion Subject of Latest Pub Night" cuts of at "latest".

The titles are stored in UILabels that are usually multilined, and I noticed that the titles are always cut off at the end of the second to last line.  I have the maximum number of lines set to '0' in Interface Builder and line breaks set to Word Wrap.

EDIT:

Here is a larger portion of the code.

```
  NSString *untrimmedTitle = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"];
cell.title.text = [untrimmedTitle stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(296,9999);
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [cell.title.text sizeWithFont:cell.title.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize];

//adjust the label to the the new height.
CGRect newFrame = cell.title.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
cell.title.frame = newFrame;
```

Comment: You should `NSLog` the result of `trimmed`. That how its resulting? If its correct then there's only problem of `UILabel`.

Comment: The NSLog displays the correct title. I'm auto adjusting the height of the UILabel based on the text size, I'm wondering if that's the source of the error. I added code above

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. The `maximumLabelSize` width was higher than the width  of the label in interface builder, so it wasn't autoadjusting correctly